# Having trouble placing a view on top of a canvas

Tags: android

I have read/tried all the answers on this i have found but am not getting anywhere. I am sure i am doing something screwy here but do not know what it is. If i comment out the line in the fragment:

```
container.addView(canvas);
```

...then i can see my two-way-gridview, so i am fairly sure it is beneath the canvas.
 This is from the fragment which displays all of this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workspace, container, false);

    bitmap = decodeImagedata(getArguments().getByteArray("image"));

    canvas = (WorkCanvas)activity.findViewById(R.id.work_canvas);
    if (canvas == null) {
        canvas = new WorkCanvas(context, null);
    }
    stickerView = new TwoWayGridView(context);
    StickerUseAdaper adapter = new StickerUseAdaper(context, R.layout.sticker_work_item, activity.getSelectedStickers());
    stickerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    container.addView(canvas);
    container.addView(stickerView);

    return view;
}
```

and the custom canvas class:

```
class WorkCanvas extends View {


private Context context;
private Activity activity;
private Bitmap bitmap;

public WorkCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = (Activity)context;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()),
            new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()), null);

    //this changes nothing :-(
    View stickerView = activity.findViewById(R.id.sticker_view);
    stickerView.bringToFront();
    stickerView.invalidate();
}

public void sendBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap= bitmap;
}
```

}

and the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/work">

<com.tk_squared.stickerpics.WorkCanvas
    android:id="@+id/work_canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />

<com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
    android:id="@+id/sticker_view"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:columnWidth="70dp"
    app:rowHeight="70dp"
    app:numColumns="auto_fit"
    app:numRows="auto_fit"
    app:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    app:scrollDirectionPortrait="horizontal"
    app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
    app:gravity="center" />
```

HEEEELLLLP! oh, and thanks!

Comment: So you have a view on top of a canvas. What do you expect you can do with such a thing ? (It's not a GLSurfaceView with transparent (or any) layers).

Comment: Well, I don't have a view on top of a canvas, that's the problem, i have a canvas on top of a view. As far as what i am going to do with such a thing: choose items to draw to the canvas. I don't understand the relevance of the question though...I can imaging many uses for a view on top of a canvas...buttons, etc.

Comment: You cannot do this. It does not work that way (the canvas is always on top, not layered). You could draw your  two-way-gridview, on the canvas and interpret the gestures from the canvas.

Comment: Okay, now I see. So would that be the best solution or would I be better off using some control that is layered to hold the original bitmap plus the additions? In the end the final product needs to be saved as a bitmap,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found my stupid mistake. With all due respect to Jon Goodwin, what i was attempting is totally possible, I just made a stupid error when I initialized my canvas and TwoWayGridView to a new objects rather than grabbing a reference to the objects that exist in the xml layout file. So:

```
canvas = (WorkCanvas)activity.findViewById(R.id.work_canvas);
if (canvas == null) {
    canvas = new WorkCanvas(context, null);
}
```

should be:

```
canvas = (WorkCanvas)view.findViewById(R.id.work_canvas);
```

and:

```
stickerView = new TwoWayGridView(context);
```

should be:

```
stickerView = (TwoWayGridView) view.findViewById(R.id.sticker_view);
```

Then this works fine (some fine tuning needed): the gridView is displayed above the canvas.